# median of 2 sorted array - by binary method

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, median

This is a binary method for finding the median in two arrays of equal length that are arranged in ascending order. The method returns an integer. Specifically, when the median is not a whole number, the method rounds it down. For example:

If the arrays `a1` and `a2` are as follows:

```
a1 = {1, 12, 15, 26, 38}
a2 = {12, 13, 18, 30, 45}
```

The method will return the value `16`. After merging the two arrays into one sorted array, we get:

```
{1, 12, 12, 13, 15, 18, 26, 30, 38, 45}
```

The two middle numbers in the array are `15` and `18`, and the average between them is `16` (rounded down due to dividing by wholes). Therefore, the method is designed to return `16`.

```
 /**
     * Finds the median of two sorted arrays of equal length.
     * Assumes that the input arrays are sorted in ascending order.
     *
     * The time complexity of this algorithm is O(log n), where n is the length of the input arrays. This is because the
     * binary search is performed until the subarrays reduce to a size of 2.
     * The space complexity is O(1) since the method uses a constant amount of extra space regardless of the input size.
     * The pointers and variables do not scale with the input size.
     *
     * @param arr1 The first sorted array.
     * @param arr2 The second sorted array.
     * @return The median value of the combined arrays.
     */
    public static int findMedian(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        // Get the length of the arrays (assumed to be equal)
        int n = arr1.length;

        // Initialize pointers for binary search
        int left1 = 0;
        int right1 = n - 1;
        int left2 = 0;
        int right2 = n - 1;

        // Base cases for arrays of length 0, 1, or 2
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        if (n == 1)
            return (arr1[0] + arr2[0]) / 2;
        if (n == 2)
            return (Math.max(arr1[0], arr2[0]) + Math.min(arr1[1], arr2[1])) / 2;

        // Binary search to find the median
        while (right1 - left1 > 1 || right2 - left2 > 1) {
            // Calculate midpoints for both arrays
            int mid1 = (left1 + right1) / 2;
            int mid2 = (left2 + right2) / 2;

            // Get the middle elements of both arrays
            int midElement1 = arr1[mid1];
            int midElement2 = arr2[mid2];

            // Check if the medians are equal
            if (midElement1 == midElement2) {
                return midElement1;
            }

            // Adjust pointers based on comparison of medians
            if (midElement1 < midElement2) {
                left1 = mid1;
                right2 = mid2;
            } else {
                right1 = mid1;
                left2 = mid2;
            }
        }

        // Calculate and return the rounded median for even-length arrays
        return (Math.max(arr1[left1], arr2[left2]) + Math.min(arr1[right1], arr2[right2])) / 2;
    }
```

The method does not work well when I enter arrays of even length, such as:

```
{1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 8}
```

In this case the method returns `3` instead of `4`. How can I fix it?
I need the method to return an **int** and not a **double**.

Comment: Why not just create an intermediate combined list of values and calculate the median of that, rather than juggling with two arrays?

Comment: This problem has a solution on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/editorial/): this editorial goes into detailt on methods to find the median of two sorted arrays. I hope this help.

Comment: Because this way the complexity drops to o(log n).
@daniu

Comment: @MunyaMurape You don't need a sorting algorithm to merge two already sorted arrays. But still, the merging is of course O(n) which is worse than O(log n)

Comment: @daniu Because merging two sorted arrays is O(n)  but there are better approaches which can calculate the median of two sorted arrays in O(log n)

Comment: Oh my mistake, I am deleting that comment.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/editorial/ - related